# Let P be any point inside a acute angled triangle, prove that PA.PB.AB+ PB. PC .BC +PC .PA .CA> AB .BC. CA. also equality holds if P is orthocenter.

Tags: geometry, vectors

Let $P$ be any point inside an acute angled triangle,
prove that $$PA \cdot PB \cdot AB + PB \cdot PC  \cdot BC +PC \cdot PA \cdot CA \ge 
AB\cdot BC\cdot CA$$
and equality holds if $P$ is orthocenter.
I tried with vectors taking $P$ as zero vector. But after that 
nothing better came out.
Tried using cosines and sine, but again not much useful.
Any hint?

Comment: I don't think it's correct. When $P=C$ the LHS is $0$ and RHS is a positive constant. That means (by continuity) that we can find a point inside the triangle and very close to C such that the inequality fails.

Comment: yes corrected it.

Comment: Do you know the length of PA, PB, PC according to AB BC CA? This change inequality to a trigonometry one.

Answer (score 3):

Choose a coordinate system such that $P$ is the origin. WOLOG, we will
assume $A,B,C$ are positioned counterclockwisely with respect to $P$.

Identity the Euclidean plane with the complex plane. Let $a, b, c$ be the complex numbers corresponds to $A,B,C$ respectively.

Notice

$$ab(b-a) + bc(c-b) + ca(a-c) = (b-a)(c-a)(c-b)\tag{*1}$$
By triangle inequality,  we get

$$|a||b||a-b| + |b||c||c-b| + |c||a||a-c| \ge |b-a||c-a||c-b| \tag{*2}$$
In terms of the distances among the points, this reduces to the 
desired inequality
$$PA\cdot PB \cdot AB
+ PB \cdot PC \cdot BC
+ PC \cdot PA \cdot CA
\ge AB\cdot AC \cdot BC
$$

When $P$ is orthocenter of $\triangle ABC$, we have $PA \perp BC$, $PB \perp CA$ and $PC \perp AB$. 
Since $A,B,C$ are positioned counterclockwisely with respect to $P$, following three numbers

$$i\frac{c-b}{a},\;\;i\frac{a-c}{b},\;\;i\frac{b-a}{c}$$

need to be positive real numbers. This means the three terms on LHS of $(*1)$ are positive multiples of each other. As a result,the inequality in $(*2)$ becomes an equality.

As a side note, the condition on equality is an if and only if one.

When $(*2)$ becomes an equality, the three terms on LHS of $(*1)$ need to be positive multiples of each other. We can find a complex number $\omega$ on the unit circle and three positive numbers $\lambda, \mu, \nu$ such that

$$\frac{c-b}{a} = \lambda\omega,\;\;
\frac{a-c}{b} = \mu\omega,\;\;
\frac{b-a}{c} = \nu\omega$$

Substitute these back into $(*1)$, we get
$$abc\omega(\lambda + \mu + \nu)
= -abc\lambda\mu\nu\omega^3
\implies \omega^2 = -\frac{\lambda+\mu+\nu}{\lambda\mu\nu} < 0$$
Since $A,B,C$ are positioned counterclockwisely with respect to $P$
and $|\omega| = 1$, we find $\omega = -i$ . From these, we can deduce $PA \perp BC$, $PB \perp CA$ and $PC \perp AB$. This means $P$ lies on the 3 altitudes of $\triangle ABC$ and is the orthocenter.

Up to my knowledge, this inequality is discovered by T. Hayashi in early 1910s.

- T. Hayashi, Two theorems on complex number, *Tôhoku Math*. J., 4 (1913-1914), 68–70.